# Will MICE imputation accuracy be harmed by removing all duplicates?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

I'm working with a very large amount of data, using the PMM method via R Mice. The data has a healthy number of continuous variables. I'm removing all the duplicates entries before starting the process.

```
unique_data=unique(data)
imputation=parlmice(unique_data, m=1000, maxit=20)
```

Merging the output back onto the original dataset should be fine, right? Or will this somehow negatively impact the quality of imputations in some way? Would appreciate tips on better/other ways to economize on memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If removing data changes the distribution of the data, say if there were originally more males than females but after removing duplicates they were equal in number, that can cause bias in the imputations. Even if the distribution of the data remains the same after removing duplicate entries, having fewer observations will result in the imputation models having larger variance. This will increase the variance of the replacement values, resulting in less powerful results.

Also, note that using `unique()` will also remove any duplicated missing values. That would mean that each imputed dataset will have the same replacement value for any identical observations. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Below is a short example of removing duplicate entries causing bias in the results. Unfortunately I don't have any advice for large data other than the standard advice to carefully consider the variables used as predictors for each imputation model.

```r
library(mice)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
set.seed(1)

dat <- matrix(data = c(
  rep(c(0,2), times = 20),
  rep(c(0,3), times = 20),
  rep(c(1,4), times = 5),
  rep(c(1,5), times = 5),
  rep(c(1,6), times = 10),
  rep(c(1,NA), times = 20)),
  nrow = 80, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()
# Indexes to remove duplicate entires but keep missing
uni_indexes <- c(1,21,41,46,51,61:80)
dat_uni <- dat[uni_indexes,]
dat_removed <- dat[-uni_indexes,]

imps1 <- mice(dat, m = 500,
              printFlag = FALSE)
imps2 <- mice(dat_uni, m = 500, 
              printFlag = FALSE)
imps2 <- rbind(imps2,dat_removed)

# confirm same final number of rows
nrow(complete(imps1, action = 1))
#> [1] 80
nrow(complete(imps2, action = 1))
#> [1] 80
# Fit models
mod1 <- with(imps1, lm(V2 ~ V1))
mod2 <- with(imps2, lm(V2 ~ V1))

summary(pool(mod1))
#>          term estimate std.error statistic       df      p.value
#> 1 (Intercept)  2.50000 0.1078115  23.18862 76.06647 0.000000e+00
#> 2          V1  2.74695 0.2446215  11.22939 28.91306 4.640288e-12
summary(pool(mod2))
#>          term estimate std.error statistic       df     p.value
#> 1 (Intercept)   2.5000  0.157987 15.824083 76.06647 0.00000e+00
#> 2          V1   2.1285  0.272824  7.801734 50.46090 3.17963e-10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>